# How can i show the relationship between a sequence in a space in norm E with a genuinely increasing sequence of natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Supposing i have a sequence $(a_n)_{n\epsilon\mathbb{N}}$ in a space with norm E .

How can i show that a sequence $(x_n)_{n\epsilon\mathbb{N}}$ exists in E , so that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0 $ and a genuinely increasing sequence $(k_n)$ of natural numbers so that $a_n = x_0 + x_1 +x_2 +x_3+...+x_{k_n} \forall n\epsilon\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

You need
$$
x_{k_{n}+1}+...+ x_{k_{n+1}}=a_{n+1}-a_n
$$
Try to pick inductively $k_{n+1}$ such that
$$
\|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{k_{n+1}-k_n}  \| < \frac{1}{n}
$$
and set
$$
x_{k_{n}+1}=...= x_{k_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{k_{n+1}-k_n} 
$$